# Prevent cascading failures in Kafka consumers

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, reliability

Imagine you have a Kafka consumer group with 3 members (M1, M2, and M3). Each member is running in it's own process, and each currently has one partition assigned (Pa, Pb, and Pc).

M1 receives a poison message from P1 which is crafted such that it triggers a stack overflow exception, killing M1. This will eventually trigger a rebalance, and M2 now has P1.

M2 will now receive the same poison message from P1 - and also die, triggering a rebalance and giving P1 to M3.

Finally, M3 will receive the same message and die.

At this point you have taken out your entire set of processors - and any new ones you spin up will also die until you have fixed the message in Kafka directly.

My question is - how does one prevent this cascading failure? I'm happy that the affected partition is ignored until the issue is resolved, and I can see how I would use the Pause functionality to achieve this in the case of a handled exception. However, I can't handle a stack overflow, so am not able to easily pause the partition.

Does Kafka have any mechanisms for handling this type of cascading failure?

Comment: We can use **assign(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)** method avoid such scenarios.

Comment: What do you mean by poison message?

Comment: @ward it's the term for a message that halts the consumer/deserializer so that it cannot continue under normal circumstances

Comment: @AshishBhosle So each microservice only reads from a specific set of partitions, thus ensuring that messages in one  partition can take out, at most, 1 instance of a microservice? That introduces a whole new set of problems, but does also accurately answer my question :-) Please can you kindly post it as an answer, and I'll accept it in a couple of days (just in case there are other answers forthcoming)

Comment: @RB. Sure will answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best question on Apache Kafka.

Well we can use **assign(Collection partitions)** method to avoid such scenarios. In this particular case we can do the following:

M1

```
    Consumer<K, V> m1 = getConsumer();
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic", 0);
    m1.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
```

M2

```
    Consumer<K, V> m2 = getConsumer();
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic", 1);
    m2.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
```

M3

```
    Consumer<K, V> m3 = getConsumer();
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic", 2);
    m3.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
```

NOTE: Above code is just an example

You can find detailed explanation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

**If you need any further help let me know. Happy to help.**

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the downside to this is that you will have to manage partition registration manually - Kafka will no longer do it for you, but otherwise, great answer, thanks :)

Comment: There are ways to avoid that too. You can store partition on shared storage, then get it and increment it. We had Apache Ignite, and one day I noticed that I can use IgniteAtomicLong for this purpose (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/atomic-types#overview). This is just to help you to find something similar. In my opinion Redis will do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

Not to be snarky, but I'd surmise the best way to prevent a stack overflow from breaking processes would be to prevent a stack overflow. Anything else would essentially be a band-aid.

It is virtually guaranteed that any exception, including stack overflows, that are encountered on one consumer will be encountered in all other instances of that consumer, given enough messages.

With that in mind, and that there are limited software-means of handling stack-overflow exceptions, the only path I could recommend in good consciousness is to pre-empt these kinds of exceptions before they happen.

If there are circumstances that prevent you from being able to prevent these exceptions, then more information might help us give more-detailed answers.

Comment: I was really using Stack Overflow exceptions as an example of "things that will terminate a process upon receiving a message" - other examples might be sloppy coding, or an unmanaged memory access exception. The question is about how to prevent a failure *cascading* to the rest of your instances, thus causing your entire set of microservices to fall over. Does Kafka support anything to help prevent that?

Comment: I think Ashish addresses your question perfectly. 

I would still challenge a bit of the premise, though, which is that one kafka partition will get a poisoned message, and other partitions won't. If there is a problem with sloppy coding or unmanaged memory access in one instance of aconsumer, there is a problem with sloppy coding and memory access in all other instances of the consumer.  Unless you only handle a handful of messages, the chances are good that you won't have many scenarios where only one consumers receives  a poisoned message.  Hopefully manual partition assignment solves it.